# Create user on remote linux with Jenkins

Tags: linux, ubuntu, jenkins, ssh

I need to run a ssh script on a remote linux server to add a user but nothing I do quite works.

I make up the username of 2 Parameters and then try to make the password of which the first part is a set string but the second part is also a Parameter. I am using the Jenkins SSH Plugin to run scripts over ssh. The first part, useradd works because I disabled sudo password for the admin user. But the passwd doesnt want to work...

I am currently trying:

```
sudo useradd $FIRSTPART1_$SECONDPART2
echo -e 'PASSWORD_$SECONDPART2\nPASSWORD$SECONDPART2\n' | sudo passwd $FIRSTPART1_$SECONDPART2
```

I suspect the problem is the double-paramaters after each other.

any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use double quotes instead of single for the echo command.

Further, without using the ssh plug-in, you can have it simple and execute a bash script locally on the build machine (e.g. in the custom build step where you can provide / write a script), provided you have ssh login without password (e.g. via key) enabled such that jenkins user can login to the target:

```
# Login
ssh user@remote << ENDSSH
# use normal commands as you would on shell or a local script;
# any variables set previously in this bash script remain valid though
sudo useradd $FIRSTPART1_$SECONDPART2
echo -e "PASSWORD_$SECONDPART2\nPASSWORD$SECONDPART2\n" | sudo passwd $FIRSTPART1_$SECONDPART2
ENDSSH
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks, going to give it a shot first thing tomorrow morning! Thanks.

Comment: hi @planetmaker, this works fine from the cmd line of Jenkins (ubuntu server console), however when I run it through Jenkins interface I get: [workspace] $ /bin/sh -xe /tmp/hudson39674804574985594.sh
+ ssh xxxxxxx@10.0.0.x
Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.
Warning: Permanently added '10.0.0.x' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
Permission denied, please try again.
Permission denied, please try again.
Permission denied (publickey,password).
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure